# What is the total number of sets that LEGO has released?

Tags: sets, lego-group

I am wondering how many LEGO sets that LEGO has released in total in their 85+ years of business. To clarify I am only looking for sets that use plastic blocks like the ones we have today, not the very early sets. This would probably be sets from [after 1950](https://www.lego.com/en-us/aboutus/lego-group/the-lego-group-history/) as they started producing the interlocking plastic brick in 1949.

Comment: A follow up question could be: Who has collected and BUILT the largest number of different Lego brand sets?

Comment: @Dan1138, you should probably start a new question rather than commenting

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It might be impossible to give the precise number simply because some older sets are yet to be found and new ones are being added with a slight delay.

These three are major websites having the most details about sets:

1. [Bricklink catalog](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=S&itemBrand=1000) has 15824 sets in its catalog.
2. [Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets) has 16378 sets.
3. [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/home/) has 15432 sets.

As you can see numbers are similar, yet differ slightly. This is due the fact that each site has its own set of rules. For example, it may treat some sets as accessories, thus including/excluding them.

**Note**. All numbers are up-to-date as of the time of this answer.

Comment: That will have to do as I should have specified in my question that I was only looking for an approximate value.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Bricklink catalog mostly lists sets that real people really have. Some of them may be sets the Lego never "shipped" and there may be other sets that Lego shipped but no living person has.

Comment: @Dan1138 Isn't that the whole point of having a catalog with ALL sets, even if the set is extremely hard to get hold of?

Answer (score 0):

There is over 2000 Lego sets. As a former employee that has been working in the design department since 2006.

Comment: Hi Michael and welcome to Bricks.SE! Your answer sets a lower boundary which is way below the ballpark established by Alex's answer, which sources three different sites. I feel this answer could be improved by either explaining the difference or expanding on the sources this answer is derived from.

Comment: Could you specify what makes these sets fall into the "set" category? Are they only official boxed sets?

Answer (score -1):

I saw in a Google search that an online database had about 20,000 Lego sets.

Comment: Hi Marble and welcome to Bricks.SE! Which database was this?